# C fscanf segmentation fault error "No source available for "flockfile() at 0x7fff855e6d39"

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, scanf

I'm currently working on an old coding problem from USACO in C. Here are the first couple lines of my code, in which I am trying to use the `fscanf()` function to grab the first value, an `int`, from the `blocks.in` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
     FILE *fin  = fopen ("blocks.in", "r");
     FILE *fout = fopen ("blocks.out", "w");
     int i,j;
     int linecount = 0;
     int alphabetCount[26];
     fscanf(fin," %d",&linecount);
```

Running gdb (as a part of the Eclipse C/C++ IDE), I consistently get a segmentation fault error on the line:

```
fscanf(fin," %d",&linecount);
```

The error consistently reads:

> No source available for "flockfile() at 0x7fff855e6d39"

I haven't been able to source the issue. I've not had any problems with this in the past. Do you see what is wrong, or have a better solution/function with which to extract the data?

Comment: Perhaps `fin  = fopen ("blocks.in", "r")` failed.  Test `if (fin)` before `fscanf(fin," %d",&linecount);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that there is no `blocks.in` file in the directory from which you run the program. Even if the file is present, it may not open successfully. Some simple error-checking could help you avoid problems here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fin;
    FILE *fout;
    int i,j;
    int linecount = 0;
    int alphabetCount[26];

    if ((fin = fopen("blocks.in", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((fout = fopen("blocks.out", "w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open output file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }     

    fscanf(fin," %d",&linecount);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do have a blocks.in file in the same directory as the program. An identical procedure has worked on past programs I've written so I think that it is unlikely that this is the case.

Comment: @JordanAndo-- Interesting. When I run your code without a `blocks.in` file on my system, I get a segfault. With the file present, no problems. Also, with the error-checking (which you should be doing, always) even without the file present there is no segfault, just the error message. Even if the file is present, it may not be opening successfully; I suggest you add the error-checking before trying anything else.

Comment: I added the error checking and it turns out that the file wasn't opening properly. I redid the blocks.in file and it appears to be working fine. Thank you for your help!